# How many sides does a circle have?

Tags: geometry, education, circles

My son is in 2nd grade.  His math teacher gave the class a quiz, and one question was this:

> If a triangle has 3 sides, and a rectangle has 4 sides, 
>   how many sides does a circle have?

My first reaction was "0" or "undefined".  But my son wrote "$\infty$" which I think is a reasonable answer.  However, it was marked wrong with the comment, "the answer is 1".

Is there an accepted correct answer in geometry?

**edit:** I ran into this teacher recently and mentioned this quiz problem.  She said she thought my son had written "8." She didn't know that a sideways "8" means infinity.

Comment: Ridiculous teacher, IMO.

Comment: It sounds very likely that the teacher did not make clear what they considered a "side" to be and whether or not the term is applicable to circles.

Comment: The question is incomplete as stated.  Saying that a triangle has 3 sides and a rectangle has 4 sides is not a good definition of "sides."  This is quite a ridiculous question for 2nd grade students.  The question can only confuse, and has no definite answer based on this definition.

Comment: Clearly the teacher thinks that $lim_{n \to +\infty}n = 1$. Does the teacher have an account somewhere that I can downvote?

Comment: to define a circle requires an infinite system of linear inequalities

Comment: What is a definition of side such that the answer is 1? I cant really think of one

Comment: @solomoan: well, maybe if $\Omega$ is a bounded region in the plane, a **side** of $\Omega$ is a maximal smooth curve inside the boundary of $\Omega$.  Of course I agree that this is a ridiculous question and that the student's answer shows at least as much insight as the teacher's.

Comment: This is a lot like "Guess whether I am thinking of A, B, C, or D."

Comment: @Douglas Zare: C?

Comment: Archimedes sure is going to roll in his grave with this one...

Comment: $\infty$ is clearly the best answer.  Perhaps your son could introduce the teacher to non-euclidean geometry where a great circle on a sphere is a 1-sided polygon.  Probably not what the teacher intended.

Comment: Thank you for adding the edit about your conversation with the teacher!  I don't know whether that makes me feel better or worse about the story.

Comment: I'm sorta kinda depressed that a *teacher* doesn't know the symbol... \*sigh\*

Comment: @Aryabhata: Now more than ever...

Comment: @Asaf: Very sad.

Comment: @J.M. Isn't "sorta kinda" an oxymoron?

Comment: @Peter: more of a joke, actually.

Comment: Of course the proper answer would have been $\mathfrak c$ ;-)

Comment: More important, you have a second grader (now going into 5th?) whose understanding of the question was perfect. I have great respect for teachers in general, but they should be tested now and then. A math teacher should ace exams at least at the level they are teaching. Which is why my state has different qualification exams for middle school and high school math.

Comment: the answers are very fancy here, the right answer is : infinite

Comment: Two: it has an outside and an inside.

Comment: So I assume then that an answer of infinity would necessarily mean a vertex count of infinity?

Comment: The expectations for today's teachers should be very low, since (most likely) they didn't have the knowledge or skill to advance in a certain field, and pursued teaching with no other option.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: since _sorta_ and _kinda_ are redundant rather than contradictory, _sorta kinda_ is a pleonasm rather than an oxymoron.

Comment: @PJTraill I waited 6 years for this comment. Thank you.

Comment: Joke: A circle has two sides  "Inside" and "outside"

Comment: About the teacher: the less, the better!

Comment: Ridiculous teacher! Your son is onto something! If you inscribe regular polygons having an ever larger number of sides, the circle is the figure obtained in the limit.!

Comment: Incidentally not a fan of this question. What is the point of this question? The teacher’s answer (1 side) makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

The answer depends on the definition of the word "side." I think this is a terrible question (edit: *to put on a quiz*) and is the kind of thing that will make children hate math. "Side" is a term that should really be reserved for polygons.

Comment: I don't think the question is terrible in itself, but asking it without realizing that there are arguments in favour of $0$, $1$ and $\infty$ and marking $\infty$ as wrong is catastrophic.

Comment: Or the more common interpretation of the question, "2 sides, inside and outside"

Comment: i'm a bit confused. why a circle doesn't have infinitely many sides? it has infinitely many tangents, right?

Comment: @Donotalo: again, it really depends on the definitions. In my opinion "side" should be restricted to polygons. One should define a polygon as a simple closed piecewise-linear curve in the plane with finitely many linear pieces and the number of sides of a polygon as the number of linear pieces. I don't really see the point of extending this definition beyond the piecewise-linear case.

Comment: I don't think that this is a terrible question. The terrible thing is to pretend there is a unique answer. Instead, this kind of thing can be a motivation to explain the (non-unique) nature of generalizations and the nature of precise definitions.

Comment: @user9325: let me clarify. This is a terrible question to put on a _quiz._ (I really thought this was clear from context, but apparently I was mistaken.)

Comment: @Qiaochu: Sorry, you are right, of course.

Comment: @Qiaochu: If you're editing, then you should say that it is actually a terrible question for a "closed form" quiz for children. I think that putting that as an open question in a quiz for math undergrads can produce interesting results.

Comment: @Asaf: I really do not think there is a need to be so incredibly precise about what I mean by "quiz."

Comment: @Qiaochu: I was actually particular about the audience, not about the definition. Because it doesn't make much sense to put this in a second grade quiz, but might make sense in a philosophy/math undergrad quiz.

Comment: @Asaf: I disagree. This would be much more productive as a class discussion. It's too much of a trick question to reasonably ask in a setting where the students will be graded on their answers.

Comment: @Qiaochu: This is why I said an open question, I would much prefer to see the students defend their own arguments in a sound and consistent way.

Comment: Value of $\pi $ Can be found by considering a circle as a nearly infinite sided polygon.

Comment: NS John is right. We can be found Pi number if the number of faces are infinite. Also the more sides you add to a polygon the more it resembles to a circle. Sure you can set this a different case but if you go deeper into analysis, it only makes sense with the rest of mathematics if you treat it as a polygon with infinite number of faces.

Answer (score 136):

My third-grade son came home a few weeks ago with similar homework questions:

> How many faces, edges and vertices do the following
>    have?
>
> - cube
> - cylinder
> - cone
> - sphere

Like most mathematicians, my first reaction was that for
the latter objects the question would need a precise
definition of face, edge and vertex, and isn't really
sensible without such definitions.

But after talking about the problem with numerous people, conducting a kind of social/mathematical experiment, I observed something intriguing. What I observed was that
none of my non-mathematical friends and acquaintances had
any problem with using an intuitive geometric concept here,
and they all agreed completely that the answers should be

- cube: 6 faces, 12 edges, 8 vertices
- cylinder: 3 faces, 2 edges, 0 vertices
- cone: 2 faces, 1 edge, 1 vertex
- sphere: 1 face, 0 edges, 0 vertices

Indeed, these were also the answers desired by my
son's teacher (who is a truly outstanding teacher). Meanwhile, all of my mathematical
colleagues hemmed and hawed about how we can't really
answer, and what does "face" mean in this context anyway,
and so on; most of them wanted ultimately to say that a
sphere has infinitely many faces and infinitely many
vertices and so on. For the homework, my son wrote an explanation giving the answers above, but also explaining that there was a sense in which some of the answers were infinite, depending on what was meant.

At a party this past weekend full of
mathematicians and philosophers, it was a fun game to first
ask a mathematician the question, who invariably made various objections and refusals and and said it made no sense and so on, and then the
non-mathematical spouse would forthrightly give a completely clear
account. There were many friendly disputes about it that evening.

So it seems, evidently, that our extensive mathematical training has
interfered with our ability to grasp easily what children and
non-mathematicians find to be a clear and distinct
geometrical concept.

(My actual view, however, is that it is our training that has taught us that the concepts are not so clear and distinct, as witnessed by numerous borderline and counterexample cases in the historical struggle to find the right definitions for the $V-E+F$ and other theorems.)

Comment: Okay, so these are "manifolds with (manifolds with boundary) as boundaries," faces describe the manifold parts, edges describe the manifold parts of the boundaries, and vertices describe the boundaries of the boundaries. That's fine as far as that goes, but not having formal definitions in this situation is just going to make it harder for you to distinguish between the different types of faces and edges implied by those counts, and consequently you'll have a harder time discovering Euler's formula. What we lose in our ability to answer trick questions we gain in _Euler's formula._

Comment: "... our extensive mathematical training has interfered with our ability to grasp easily what children and non-mathematicians find to be a clear... concept." - I believe this largely applies to such "find the (integer) pattern" problems as can be found on IQ tests and the like. The mathematicians claim infinite solutions; the non-mathematicians actually fill in *an answer*! Thanks for your answer, by the way.

Comment: @The Chaz: that's a bad example. Your ability to answer such questions is not necessarily related to any objective measure of intelligence: it correlates with being familiar with certain examples of such questions and more generally with being raised in a culture where such questions exist. When mathematicians react negatively to the use of such questions, they are in part reacting to this arbitrariness (at least I am). Being able to answer such questions indicates that you are good at anticipating what kind of answers the makers of the test want, nothing more and nothing less.

Comment: I have long thought you must be great to have around at parties :)

Comment: I think this answer could be a great upstep to an interesting discussion on the balance between intuition and rigor, and how the latter may sometimes hinder mathematical advancement. However, I must agree with Qiaochu Yuan that in the particular case of a teacher asking such a question it seems more appropriate to begin a discussion about the lack of mathematical skill and understanding displayed by teachers and how _that_ hinders mathematical advancement.

Comment: Qiaochu, your manifolds-with-manifolds-with-boundaries-boundaries definition is of
course very natural, and most of us would be tempted in
that direction. But does it give the right calculation for
the cone? After all, third-graders and third-grade teachers
will insist that a cone has one edge (the bottom circle)
and one vertex (the top point), but this vertex is not on the
boundary of that edge. (But I suppose one could equivocate about non-empty edges, etc.)

Comment: Mariano, thanks for the vote of confidence! (And next time you are in New York, please let me know.)

Comment: @JDH: fair enough. How about this: I think the definition of the tangent space at a point via equivalence classes of smooth curves works in this situation, and then I believe it's true that the naive count of faces, edges, etc. counts connected components of the subspaces of points whose tangent spaces have the relevant dimensions.

Comment: @Myself, I agree with your first point, but not your second, as my son's teacher, as I mentioned, is truly outstanding. The homework questions I mention are not a case of mathematical ineptitude (particularly because she was open to the possibility of more sophisticated answers discussing the issue as here, unlike the teacher of the OP above).

Comment: @JDH Of course my own comment on 'teachers' was a reference to the OP's story, where a teacher will (apparently) vigorously defend his or her own version of truth, based on some definitions that were never clearly stated. I was certainly not making a statement about teachers in general.

Comment: Your writing is beautiful and wonderful. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AndrewOstergaard You are very kind to say so; thank you very much.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan The sequence extrapolation problem can be seen as the problem of finding continuations of a sequence with low [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity). The ability to find such low-complexity hypotheses or explanations [is a measure of universal intelligence](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0004370210001554) (see also [Solomonoff induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomonoff%27s_theory_of_inductive_inference)).

Comment: I have posted a question about this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3613078/what-captures-our-intuitive-notion-of-faces-edges-and-vertices), in case anyone is interested.

Comment: "...my non-mathematical friends and acquaintances had any problem with using an intuitive geometric concept here..." this statement is a bit of a stretch. It's odd to assume "non-mathematical" friends would answer correctly in the first place--so I don't even understand the premise: "my friends without knowledge came to an incorrect conclusion thus their conclusion must be better than others..."

The answer zero makes no sense--because it's avoiding the question. If your "answer" is zero, then you are critiquing the question itself--which would be your answer--not zero.

Comment: @Jared In your second quotation, you use quotation marks to criticize me, but those are not words that I said. Indeed, I wouldn't have, since my friends are not without knowledge—they are quite smart. And I think you may have missed the point of my post, which was not to argue for those answers but rather to highlight the fact that sometimes expert knowledge prevents us from seeing the sense in a different perspective. You say "the answer zero makes no sense," which shows that you suffer from this phenomenon, since those answers are not without some sense.

Comment: @JDH ....I guess so--I mean it must be so because I can't see it from any other perspective other than we define things to be true or anything you like is true--then if it's the latter, I'm definitively wrong--because even worse than being wrong--there are an infinite number of ways to interpret _anything!_

Comment: No, I'm not defending "anything you like is true."

Comment: @JDH FWIW, I "understand" the perspective of "zero is the answer". The answer is to a question of "how many segments make up a circle?" The answer zero means that you do not think there are _any definable_ segments that make up a circle--thus the answer to the "number" of them is zero. You are counting the number of definitions that you made. I can create an n-regular-polygon that will look virtually identical with a circle and we'll all agree it as $n$-sides. I will will then "snap" it to a circle where all of the segments have collapsed, so "no more segments exist".

Comment: @JDH Sorry--I think my answer is obfuscating my point. "How many sides does a circle have?" Answer: it's easy to argue it's an infinite-sided polygon, or maybe it's something else. The "obvious" answer has now been shown to be "incorrect" (possibly falsely incorrect--which would be my point) by the fact that you're asking it. So while they may truly believe that a circle has infinite sides, they will now try to construct an argument that says it doesn't (which will ultimately be a semantics argument--i.e. what are your definitions?)

Comment: @Jared I think I had said in my answer what I wanted to say, and so I'll just let it stand at that.

Answer (score 36):

I know I'm late to the party, but I'm surprised noone has mentioned this. In convexity theory, there is a notion called an extreme point that generalizes the notion of vertex (or corner) of a polygon. For this definition every point on a circle is an extreme point so it makes sense to say it has infinitely (uncountably!) many corners. Though the notion of side is not as good. If the definition is line segment joining two vertices then the answer would be 0 for the circle.

Comment: I had my downvotes at the ready, expecting the usual tripe spouted by someone digging up an ancient question - but *great answer*.

Answer (score 25):

This is in reference to Douglas Stones' answer, but images can't be imbedded in comments.  Limits of sides can have a straight angle, such as these octogons converging to a square.

[image: octogons]

A straight line could be any number of sides with straight angles between them.

Answer (score 22):

For those who are thinking that the answer is $\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} n = \infty$, via:

- An $n$-gon has $n$ sides;
- A circle is a limit of a $n$-gon as $n \rightarrow \infty$;
- Therefore a circle has $\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} n = \infty$ sides;

I'd like to mention:  it's not so straightforward.  If taking limits in this way were legitimate then we can show that e.g. a square has an infinite number of sides.

Consider a staircase with $n$ steps, and each step has height $1/n$ and width $1/n$.  It consists of $2n$ line segments.  As $n \rightarrow \infty$, the staircase converges to a single line segment (i.e. the limit agrees point-for-point with a single line segment).

If we glue four of these staircases together, and take their limit, we obtain a square, which would have $\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} 4 \times 2n = \infty$ sides.

Comment: [Hehehe...](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12906)

Comment: @Douglas: 1.Define "line"? 2. Define "Gluing"

Comment: @Douglas: I think the reasoning was not like that, but on the line of "a triangle has three tangents, a square has four, and a circle has infinitely many.

Comment: @DouglasS.Stones  `If taking limits in this way were legitimate then we can show that e.g. a square has an infinite number of sides.` is a good example of similar flaw,  but,  not clear where the flaw or what the flaw is. Can you please explain the logical flaw then? Why we can't take limit here?

Comment: This is an excellent response to those who think that a circle has infinite sides. Those people are assuming that 'side' means 'straight edge', whereas my belief is that side means 'smooth edge' (at least in this context).
My daughter (8) had the same question in her schoolwork today, and she put 0, but I told her it should be 1 (and yes, I am a mathematician).

Comment: If you assume a staircase approximates a straight line, then a square (if we assume we can only take horizontal/vertical steps) doesn't exist. It's still wrong--but even worse now, you're arguing a straight line doesn't exist!

Answer (score 9):

Both answers 1 and $\infty$ are intuitively correct.

To the answer "$\infty$":
Imagine that you start with circle. Now you can try approximate the circle by a centered (at middle of circle) hexagon. The next step is to double the number of corners to a regular dodecagon and so on. What you see geometrically is that the $n$-th regular polygon by this construction will approximate the circle better than the $(n-1)$-th one. You can look now at the number of sides during this approximation by doubling the number of corners:
$6\to12\to24\to48\to96...\to6\cdot2^n=3\cdot2^{n+1}$. Taking $n\to\infty$ you see that you get $\infty$ sides. (but their length goes to zero...)

To the answer "1":
On the other hand it is not intuitive to call it a "side" while its length$\to0$, which is the state in a circle (remember the definition of a circle as a set of points). But what you get is a curved line (the circle itself), which one could interpret as a "side" because it separates the inner region from its environment. And this is **one** line. This could be the reason for the answer "circle has one side".

However: "$\infty$ or 1?" is a question which causes from the question of the definition of the word "side". (and as one can see "side" makes only really sense for polygons)

Comment: -1 for the "answer could be $\infty$" part. That a figure can be approximated to arbitrary precision by polygons with sufficiently high number of sides is not a good definition of having an infinite number of sides. See the answers by Douglas Stones and robjohn.

Answer (score 7):

Personally I use to think a circle had infinite sides as well; however, why could it not be one side with a $360^\circ$ curve?

Comment: Why could it not be 3 sides that happen to coincide?

Comment: Or four sides, three of which have size 0.

Comment: Because, as I said, the answer depends on the definition of the word "side." The most restrictive definition is that such a thing has to be straight, and in that definition there are no sides.

Answer (score 4):

A circle has indeed $0$ straight sides.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer to this question relies heavily on the CW structure imposed on $S^1$. I can realise $S^1$ with an arbitrary number of $1$-cells.

Comment: One can realize a triangle with an arbitrary number of $1$-cells.

Comment: Yes. I think you can proof this by using a homeomorphism from the triangle to the circle.

Comment: We would never use "number of $1$-cells in a CW structure imposed on the figure" to count the sides of a polygon, so why would we use it to count sides of a circle?

Answer (score 2):

One way to understand the question and demonstrate applicability is to consider the problem and efficiency of finding the area of the union of 2 overlapping circles versus 2 overlapping rectangles or squares.

Let us now constrain the union area to be constant.

In the case of circles it will always be the same shape, no matter which way the circles are positioned in relation to one another.

In the case of squares, it would be the same shape too.

In case of rectangles, the shape would vary.

We could here argue that the circle and square both have 1 side, because they are defined by a single length (radius or diagonal), or in other words, they have no apparent "orientation".

Answer (score 1):

In my humble opinion, all answers from zero up to infinity (as long as it's a natural number) are acceptable: if you define a triangle having three sides (straight segments) and a rectangle having four sides (straight segments), then the amount of sides is zero indeed.

If you want to know the amount of lines (straight or curved) you need in order to draw a circle, then the answer might be one, but this also means that a triangle or a rectangle also might have just one side.

The infinity answer is correct, because a circle is the infinite limit of a regular polygon, consisting of $n$ sides (straight segments).

... but one thing is not mentioned here: a triangle is said consisting of three sides (straight segments), but this is not true at all: triangles consist of **at least** three sides, hereby an example of a triangle with three sides:
[image]

One with four sides:
[image]

One with five sides:
[image]

=> that's how difficult mathematics become if you don't use strict definitions!

Answer (score 0):

The question assume Euclidean geometry, What we call $d_2$.

In Euclidean geometry, the distance between two points is given by:

$$\sqrt{(x_a-x_b)^2+(y_a-y_b)^2}$$

But this formula can be generalized for more distances:

$$d_p=\sqrt[p]{\vert x_a-x_b\vert^p+\vert y_a-y_b \vert^p}$$

Then we have two special cases:

$$d_1=\vert x_a-x_b\vert+\vert y_a-y_b \vert$$

Which is the Manhattan distance.

$$d_\infty=\sqrt[\infty]{\vert x_a-x_b\vert^\infty+\vert y_a-y_b \vert^\infty}=\max(\vert x_a-x_b\vert,\vert y_a-y_b\vert)$$

Which is the max distance.

Manhattan distance will give you a circle balancing on one apparent vertex.
Max distance will give you a circle lying on one of it's four apparent sides.

$p$ can take any real value in $[1,\infty)$ and the shape would still be a circle, though **visually**, it would morph between two "squares".

The reality is that you've to define "side" properly. It's where you've to abandon the visuals as they are utterly misleading.
And intuition is also really good a misleading.

This is a cautionary tale that even the simplest thing is just a nightmare to work with.

Also, I didn't mention the range $]0,1)$ because we obtain strange figures.

The formula for a circle with its center at the origin and of radius one is given by:

$$\sqrt[p]{\vert x\vert^p+\vert y\vert^p}=1$$

You can toy with the circle here: https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/hdguujtr

If you find that "weird", there is even a metric defined as:

$$\cases{1\text{ if both points are different}\\0\text{ if both point are the same}}$$

It's a good exercise to try to think about how would a circle of radius one look like in that metric. (it's rewarding a mind bending)

Answer (score 0):

All three can be correct with explanation--guessing is *not* correct (also bad teacher regardless--as a former math teacher, I've seen it and it's unfortunate).

infinite (in my opinion the most correct): we can approximate a circle by an $n$-regular-polygon--as the the number of sides goes to infinity, the polygon approaches a true circle.

1: an $n$-polygon has $n$ sides--a circle has a single "straight" edge--a boundary...just as all polygons have a boundary--suggesting that polygons in fact have a single side (inside or out).

0: ahhhh zero--the answer to every counting question if you frame it properly...Just as above, a circle is not a polygon--I can't define its sides, therefore it has exactly "no sides", zero.

and undefined: basically the more honest answer to "zero". Edges are only defined for polygons--since a circle is not a polygon, the question is undefined.

Personally the only correct answer (to me) is infinity as it's the only sane answer. "0" and "undefined" simply skirt the question and basically say that shapes are shapes and are not polygons even though we absolutely know, empirically, that absolutely *any* shape can be approximated by a polygon with enough and small enough sides. "1" as the answer makes almost no sense to me because I don't know how you define that a polygon has several sides (edges) yet a circle or curved surface has only one (what are you saying is an edge/side then?)

Answer (score -3):

***A Line Segment contain infinite points and Sinc you are talking about a side then we can treat the side as Line Segment.***

***If we take a regular n-sided polygon where n tends to infinity then sides or Line Segment will approaches to point but not exactly point*** and in that way the regular polygon ***approaches to circle but not exactly becomes the circle***.

***Note***: In geometry , ***the line, point are undefined terms*** so we can't claim about the ***Number of sides of Circle***.

You should note that Point is dimension less means it has no length, breadth ,height and it is infinitely small quantities and these infinite points makes line so if we choose any two points on line say A and B and claim that ***distance between A and B is infinitely small*** then can we say that single point will lies Between them?
***DEFINATELY NOT***, because we can put more infinite small points between A and B.

Comment: -1 I find the "bold" and all-caps to be quite rude.