# Is there an existing graph that meets the following properties : disconnected, eulerian, hamiltonian and bipartite

Tags: graph-theory

A colleague of mine claims that there exists one, but I can't figure how an eulerian graph can be disconnected, since you have to visit all the graph vertices in the cycle...

Comment: It can’t be disconnected. Neither can a graph with a Hamilton circuit.

Comment: Maybe you should ask your colleague to exhibit the graph.

Comment: It might be a trick question with a silly answer like "empty graph". Depending on the definition the empty graph might be a disconnected one, e.g. if disconnected is defined as $\forall v \in V.\ \exists x, y \in V.\ x$ and $y$ are not connected. I _do know_ that such definition does not make sense, just giving an example.

Comment: @dtldarek, good point! [There are good reasons to consider the empty graph disconnected](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50551/is-the-empty-graph-connected). But I have no idea if it qualifies as Eulerian, Hamiltonian, or bipartite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that your colleague is using a non-standard definition by saying that the disjoint union of eulerian/hamiltonian connected components is itself eulerian/hamiltonian. If this is the case, then simply considering one connected component of the graph will suffice, and so the problem reduces to showing a connected, hamiltonian, eulerian, bipartite graph. There are many such examples, the cycle on four vertices being the smallest nontrivial example.

Comment: But the cycle of four vertices isn't a bipartite graph, isn't it ?

Comment: Sure it is. ${}$

Comment: @Pacane Label the vertices in order around the cycle $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$. The sets $\{A, C\}$ and $\{B, D\}$ are a bipartition.