# Proving that a regular polygon with infinite sides is a circle by using limits on the formula $\frac{\pi}{n}(n-2)$

Tags: geometry, limits, recreational-mathematics, circles, infinity

In childhood, when we were taught circles for the first time, our teacher always told us that a circle is like a polygon which has infinite sides. But how to prove it? 
A regular polygon's interior angle is given by $\frac\pi n(n-2)$ and when we use limits, $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac\pi n(n-2)=\pi$$ But now how do we use it to prove that this polygon is a circle in fact. 
**Edit:** We have to use this formula to prove that a polygon with infinite size is a circle.

Comment: This simply doesn't make sense---a polygon by definition has finitely many sides. One *can* say that a circle is (in various senses) a limit of a suitable sequence of polygons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97861/limit-of-the-sequence-of-regular-n-gons.

Comment: @lhf, see the edit.

Comment: Some related posts: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31785/how-many-sides-does-a-circle-have, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1164977/how-to-prove-the-infinite-number-of-sides-in-a-circle and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478005/how-can-i-show-that-a-sequence-of-regular-polygons-with-n-sides-becomes-more-a

Comment: @MartinSleziak, that image question is really really great! Thank you! But my question specifically uses the interior angle formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proof depends by the definition of a circle that we use.

If the definition is:

> the locus of points equidistant from a given point called center $C$

consider a regular  polygon with $C$ as center of symmetry. For a point on the polygon the distance $d$ from $C$ is such that:
$$
r\le d\le r\cos \dfrac{\theta}{2}
$$
where: $r$ is the distance of a vertex form $C$ and $\theta$ is the angle of vertex $C$ subtended by a side.

If the number of sides $n \rightarrow \infty$ than $\theta \rightarrow 0$ and :
$$
\lim_{\theta \to 0}r\cos \dfrac{\theta}{2}=r
$$
so, at the limit, all points of the polygon have the same distance $r$ from $C$.

if you want use the internal angle $\alpha=\dfrac{\pi}{n}(n-2)$, note that $\theta = \pi -\alpha$ and:
$$
n \rightarrow 0 \iff \alpha \rightarrow \pi \iff \theta \rightarrow 0
$$

or use:

$$
r\le d\le r \sin \dfrac {\alpha}{2}
$$

Comment: Thank you for an approach. But my question is different. This doesn't answer mine. I will edit to explain how

Comment: The interior angle of a polygon is $alpha=\pi(n-2)/n$. So you formula is not correct, and see the add to my answer.

Comment: What is $\theta$?

Comment: Defined in my answer: the angle at center $C$ that subtends a side of the polygon.

Comment: If $\theta \to 0$ how it is a circle?

Comment: It is a circle because $n \to \infty$ and this inplies $\theta \to 0$. I've added also another inequality for which you can use your limit.

Comment: How does $\theta\to 0$ imply that it is a circle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29933/discussion-between-emilio-novati-and-aditya-agarwal).