# How many corners does a cylinder have?

Tags: geometry

As per the textbook definition of a corner/vertex:

> ***Vertex***: The common endpoint of two or more rays or line segments. Vertex typically means a corner or a point where lines meet.

As per the above given definition, a cylinder should have 2 corner(right?)
Or does it have no corner as common sense dictates?

Comment: Related: [This nice answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/40266/856) to the question "[How many sides does a circle have?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/31785/856)"

Comment: @Technotoes vertex is for 2-D structures.