# What captures our intuitive notion of faces, edges, and vertices?

Tags: geometry, intuition, tangent-spaces

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/40266/76284) suggests that laypeople's intuitive notion of the meaning of these words is consistent with the following claims:

- A cube has 6 faces, 12 edges, 8 vertices.
- A cylinder has 3 faces, 2 edges, 0 vertices.
- A cone has 2 faces, 1 edge, 1 vertex.
- A sphere has 1 face, 0 edges, 0 vertices.

What formal, mathematical definition best captures this intuition and is consistent with the above claims? For example, the following was suggested in the comments:

> I think the definition of the tangent space at a point via equivalence
>   classes of smooth curves works in this situation, and then I believe
>   it's true that the naive count of faces, edges, etc. counts connected
>   components of the subspaces of points whose tangent spaces have the
>   relevant dimensions.

Is this a good approach? If so, does it have an existing name and literature? Are there any other approaches?

Comment: I don't think there's a need to talk about tangent spaces - it seems simpler to just talk about building the whole shape by gluing together connected manifolds of various dimensions (with the $0$-dimensional ones being vertices, the $1$-dimensional ones being edges, etc.). Basically, a [CW-complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex).

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I'm not convinced that the cylinder is made up of three two-dimensional CW-complexes. =D

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer: From [generalizations of manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Generalizations_of_manifolds):

> **Orbifolds:** An [orbifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbifold) is a generalization of manifold allowing for certain kinds of "singularities" in the topology. Roughly
> speaking, it is a space which locally looks like the quotients of some
> simple space (e.g. Euclidean space) by the actions of various finite
> groups. The singularities correspond to fixed points of the group
> actions, and the actions must be compatible in a certain sense.
>
> **Stratified space:** A "stratified space" is a space that can be divided into pieces ("strata"), with each stratum a manifold, with the
> strata fitting together in prescribed ways (formally, a filtration by
> closed subsets). There are various technical definitions, notably a
> Whitney stratified space (see [Whitney conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_conditions)) for smooth manifolds
> and a [topologically stratified space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologically_stratified_space) for topological manifolds.
>
> **CW-complexes:** A [CW complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex)
> is a topological space formed by gluing disks of different
> dimensionality together. In general the resulting space is singular,
> and hence not a manifold. However, they are of central interest in
> algebraic topology, especially in homotopy theory, as they are easy to
> compute with and singularities are not a concern.

From [topologically stratified space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologically_stratified_space):

> In topology, a branch of mathematics, a topologically stratified space
> is a space X that has been decomposed into pieces called strata; these
> strata are manifolds and are required to fit together in a certain
> way. Topologically stratified spaces provide a purely topological
> setting for the study of singularities analogous to the more
> differential-geometric theory of Whitney.
>
> Basic examples of stratified spaces include [manifolds with boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Manifold_with_boundary)
> (top dimension and codimension 1 boundary) and manifolds with corners
> (top dimension, codimension 1 boundary, codimension 2 corners).